# Undefined method update_attributes in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-activerecord

In Rails, I want to update my user record. I'm trying to use this command:

```
@user=User.update_attributes(:name=> params[:name], :user=> params[:username], :pass=> params[:password])
```

But I always get the error:

```
undefined method `update_attributes'
```

What's the right way to update my user?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

**Update for Rails v >= 6.1**

Use `update` method as`update_attributes` method was removed as part of [Rails 6.1 Release](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/6_1_release_notes.html#active-record-removals)

```
@user.update(name: "ABC", pass: "12345678")
```

---

**For Rails v < 6.1**

`update_attributes` is an instance method not a class method, so first thing you need to call it on an instance of `User` class.

Get the user you want to update :
e.g. Say you want to update a User with id 1

```
 @user = User.find_by(id: 1)
 now if you want to update the user's name and password, you can do
```

either

```
 @user.update(name: "ABC", pass: "12345678")
```

or

```
 @user.update_attributes(name: "ABC", pass: "12345678")
```

Use it accordingly in your case.

For more reference you can refer to [Ruby on Rails Guides](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_basics.html#update).

You can use `update_all` method for updating all records.
It is a class method so you can call it as
Following code will update name of all User records and set it to "ABC"
User.update_all(name: "ABC")

Comment: Thanks Kirti Thorat , it work now and i understand the concept to update records in rails

Comment: +1 for signalling the use of update_all on arrays. The fact that update_attributes is applicable only to a member and not a collection is rather opaque...

Comment: While this was the correct answer in 2014, If you are on newer rails use the update method.

Answer (score 24):

It seems that [as of Rails 6.1](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/6_1_release_notes.html#active-record-removals), the "**update_attributes**" method is not working anymore!
You must use the "**update**" method like this:

```
@user=User.update(:name=> params[:name], :user=> params[:username], :pass=> params[:password])
```

Comment: Thank you!  It took me a while to find this answer, and after years of using `update_attributes` I thought I was going crazy.

Comment: @MohammadBon I just recently updated rails version and am seeing this error for the first time, does this mean everywhere I use update_attributes is going to be broken?

Comment: Is this as simple as a finding all and changing them to update?  Or are there any other differences?  It seems to work fine where I just changed it in my update user method...

Comment: @PhilCowan
Yes, Just find and replace. But don't forget to push your codes before making big changes ;)