# Rails undefined method `update_attributes' for false:FalseClass

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-4, rubygems

If the dispute save the change the order boolean false to true
but after create the rails log show

> undefined method `update_attributes' for false:FalseClass

Someone know why?

```
order 
has_one :dispute

dispute
belongs_to :order


def create
    if   current_user == @order.buyer



      dispute = @order.dispute.nil? ? Dispute.new : @order.dispute

      if dispute.save
@order = params[:dispute_status] == "1"

         @order.update_attributes(:dispute_status => true)

        redirect_to order_dispute_path(@order, @dispute)
        flash[:success] = 'yess'

      else
        flash[:error] = 'Erro'
        redirect_to :back
      end
    end
  end
```

And if i remove the    @order.update_attributes(:dispute_status => true)

the logs shows :

> ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches {:action=>"create",
>   :controller=>"disputes", :order_id=>false, :format=>nil}

Comment: Possible duplicate of [undefined method update\_attributes in Rails 4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21605186/undefined-method-update-attributes-in-rails-4)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well you have @order = params[:dispute_status] == 1. This returns a boolean. In your case, probably false. So now @order is a boolean false and you are trying to call update_attributes on it.

Comment: Not what? Not a boolean? No I am pretty sure @order the way you wrote it makes it a boolean because you are setting it to the return value of params[:dispute_status] == 1

Answer (score 0):

`FalseClass.instance_methods.include?(:update_attributes)  # false
ActiveRecord::Base.instance_methods.include?(:update_attributes) # true`

your @order isn't a ActiveRecord::Base instance! clear?